How to automate secret generation/rotation in aws?
I am creating a secrets manager resource via terraform (sample code below), I looked up a few examples and understand that I can hook this resource up with a lambda for key rotation, which will generate a random secret and store it. Is there already inbuild lambda/code to do this in aws? Also, when lambda does the rotation, does it immediately expire the old key or can we set the time such that it only expires after a certain number of days. I assume the timeline can be set via lambda or terraform. Some examples would be helpful.
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "example" {
  name = "example"
}


The terraform code you have provided creates an empty secret without any value. When you store the secret in the secrets manager, you need to customize the secret values according to your specific use case, as these will depend on the type of secret you're rotating and the service it's used in - eg. api vs databases, vs login credentials. I can share my python code that is deployed as a lambda to rotate the secrets every six months. You might have to customize it based on the secret value/service you use it in.

Use another resource AWS::SecretsManager::RotationSchedule for setting the rotation schedule settings.
MySecretRotationSchedule:
  Type: AWS::SecretsManager::RotationSchedule
  DependsOn: MyRotationLambda 
  Properties:
    SecretId: !Ref MySecret
    RotationLambdaARN: !GetAtt MyRotationLambda.Arn
    RotationRules:
      Duration: 2h
      ScheduleExpression: 'cron(0 1 * * ? *)'

